# Android In-app purchase NullPointerException Purchase.getSku()

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am working on android in purchase project. I used [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/) sample code as reference.

But when execute in app purchase it return null point exception.

This is my code.

launchPurchaseFlow

```
 mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_GAS, 10001,
   mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
```

PurchaseFinish Listener

```
 IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);


            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing END"+purchase.getSku());
}
```

Error shows following line in above code

```
Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing END"+purchase.getSku());
```

I added this for testing and identify `sku`. But `purchase` object also null in here.

Error

> .util.Purchase.getSku()' on a null object reference

Comment: Log.d(TAG, purchase);
  this return null

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities one your is your code implementation is wrong and second one you have not add your account as a tester in play store console.

For checking code implementation :

try with this test sku id "android.test.purchased" if this won't work then please check you have added your account as a tester or not.